Chrome - refresh to anchor instead of last scroll position
On up-to-date Chrome (128.0.6613.85) and MacOS (14.6.1) w/ ARM, refreshing a chrome tab (whether it be normal, hard, or empty cache and hard) reloads the page to the same location as before the refresh.
The only way I've found to get Chrome to jump back to the anchor specified in the URL is by loading the same domain but to a different anchor, then switching back.
Is there a quicker way (preferably like just refreshing the page) to get back to an anchor specified in the address box?

That functionality is defined by scrollRestoration property of History API and defaults to auto, which scrolls to last position.
You could write a short userscript or extension that utilizes this code from the page above, on the pages where you'd like it to be stopped:

if (history.scrollRestoration) {
 history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
}


This will disable the behavior. However, the browser might not scroll to the anchor, still. From what I see at least latest Chrome seems to consistently stay at the top after a refresh. You could add code that works around that, in that case:
const name = location.hash.substring(1); // get anything after `#` in URL
const elem = document.getElementById(name) || document.getElementsByName(name)[0]; // elements are scrollable to through both ID and name, ID is preferred by browsers
if (elem) {
  elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}

